# How to use \pgfmathresult globally?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I have determined the x-coordinate of a point (A) and printed it next to A via

```
\node[below left] at (A) {%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
  \transformxdimension{\macrox}
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
```

Now I would like to further use \pgfmathresult and store the value in let's say a variable (or to write it to a file)

```
\xdef\xA{\pgfmathresult}
```

which however does not hold original value anymore. Is there a way to still use `\pgfmathresult` determined previously?

Thanks a lot,

Cluny

---

Attached, a mini-example, which further illustrates the idea.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5, 
    width=10cm,
}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{
  crossp/.style={
    thick,
    draw=gray,
  },
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\transformxdimension[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{((#1/\pgfplots@x@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
  }
  \makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

\begin{axis}[
    %small,
    x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm,
    ymajorgrids, xmajorgrids,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,    
    xmin=0, xmax=10,    
]   


\draw[name path global=lineA] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:10,10);
\draw[name path global=lineB] (axis cs:0,8) -- (axis cs:10,1);

\path[name intersections={of=lineA and lineB, by=A}];
\node[fill=red, circle, inner sep=1.5pt] at (A) {};

\node[left] at (A) {%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}
  \transformxdimension{\macrox}
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{\pgfmathresult}

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal working example (documentclass, needed packages, document environment).

Comment: Can't you simply use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{<your-computation>}` ?

Comment: @marsupilam: Unfortunately, redo the calculation and trying e.g., `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{\pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}\transformxdimension{\macrox}\pgfmathresult}` results in an error.

Comment: TikZ uses \pgfmathresult internally for almost everything, so you need to copy it (`\global\let\myresult=\pgfmathresult`) immediately.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That is almost what I was looking for. However, as soon as I try to put this variable to a file `\immediate\write\tempfile{\myresult}`, it states an *undefined control sequence*. With other variables I don't see this issue.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It is also not possible to use the new variable`\myresult` for simple calculations. E.g., `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myresultInc}{\myresult + 1}` throws an error as well. Hence it seems that your solution does not help here.

Comment: Did you put it inside the node?  Only globals can get out of a node.  BTW, I checked the calculation using a different approach and verified that you are getting the x coordinate of (A).

Comment: Yes, it is inside the node. Your helpful hint is very similar to the one given by egreg... But in both cases I am not possible to do something reasonable (calculation, writing into file) with the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the result *before* the statement ends.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5, 
    width=10cm,
}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{
  crossp/.style={
    thick,
    draw=gray,
  },
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\transformxdimension[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    ((#1/\pgfplots@x@veclength)+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/%
    10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x
  }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

\begin{axis}[
    %small,
    x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm,
    ymajorgrids, xmajorgrids,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,    
    xmin=0, xmax=10,    
]   


\draw[name path global=lineA] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:10,10);
\draw[name path global=lineB] (axis cs:0,8) -- (axis cs:10,1);

\path[name intersections={of=lineA and lineB, by=A}];
\node[fill=red, circle, inner sep=1.5pt] at (A) {};

\node[left] at (A) {%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}%
  \transformxdimension{\macrox}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
  \xdef\xA{\pgfmathresult}%
};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\show\xA

\end{document}
```

With this I get

```
> \xA=macro:
->4.71.
```

on the terminal.

Comment: Thank you, however, also in this case I am somehow not able to further use the variable as an operand.

Comment: @Cluny In what sense? The macro will be available for whatever purpose.

Comment: For instance,`\pgfmathsetmacro{\xAIncrement}{\xA + 1}` afterwards fails. It seems that `\xA` is kind of a wrong data type.

Comment: @Cluny If I do `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xAIncrement}{\xA + 1}`, then `\show\xAIncrement` yields `5.71`.

Comment: I see why it was failing. I tried to process \xA within the `{axis}` environment, but there \xA is somehow not defined. Anyway, operating on the variable outside of {axis} is sufficient. Thanks a lot!